# Flink Scala ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.flink.api.common.typeinfo.TypeInformation

Tags: java, scala, apache-flink, emr, flink-streaming

I am new to Flink and I was following the SocketWindowWordCount example.

I am using Scala 2.11.8 and Flink 1.3.2 and try to run it on EMR, when I run the following code, it threw errors:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.flink.api.common.typeinfo.TypeInformation
```

The main class looks like this:

```
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala._
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.time.Time

object FlinkStreamingPOC {

  def main(args: Array[String]) : Unit = {
    val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
    val stream = env.readTextFile("s3a://somebucket/prefix")
    val counts = stream.flatMap{ _.split("\\W+") }
      .map { (_, 1) }
      .keyBy(0)
      .timeWindow(Time.seconds(10))
      .sum(1)

    counts.print

    env.execute("Window Stream WordCount")
  }
}
```

build.sbt looks like this:

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

val flinkVersion = "1.3.2"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-scala" % flinkVersion,
  "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-streaming-scala" % flinkVersion
)
```

I tried to `import org.apache.flink.api.scala._` and `org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala._` but still got the same error message. Please suggest, thanks!

Comment: Try to add `<dependency> <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId <artifactId>flink-core</artifactId><version>1.3.2</version></dependency>`, TypeInformation actually is in this package.

Answer (score 11):

If you use IDEA, you can include dependencies with "Provided" scope.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Open the build.sbt file and remove the `provided` from the dependencies

Answer (score 0):

You might be having the same issue as I was having which basically involves adding the jar to `/lib` folder, please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46994916/unable-to-execute-cep-pattern-in-flink-dashboard-version-1-3-2-which-is-caused-b) for more details. In case of Amazon EMR you are using flink Dashboard . As you can see `/opt` have all the required jars which you need to copy in lib folder

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem with class `AverageSensorReadings` in project: https://github.com/streaming-with-flink/examples-scala. It's a maven project, so I commented out all `<scope>provided</scope>` for every dependency in the pom file and it works.

Answer (score 0):

The fat jar you built from a Flink project is supposed to run **inside flink cluster environment**, thus all Flink related dependencies would be provided by the environment.

Other answers suggest to simply comment out `provided` scope from the dependencies, thus include these dependencies into the fat jar. This may work, but not correct.

If you are running the jar with command like `java --classpath target/your-project-jar.jar your.package.SocketWindowWordCount`, then you are outside the Flink cluster environment.

The correct way is to use `flink run ...` command like `./bin/flink run -c your.package.SocketWindowWordCount target/your-project-jar.jar`.

Try `./bin/flink run --help` for details.